# Value of a counter is not functioning properly

Tags: java, arrays

The code is supposed to work like this :
If
`numValue[] = {500,100,1,10}` and `l=4` then it should perform *10-1+100+500* .
I have written some print statements to understand what's going wrong but I can't find it out.

> Edit: It should check from the last and if the next number is less than the previous, then it should be subtracted from  `answer` and if it is greater, then it should be added.

```
void calculate() {

    for(int i=0;i<l-1;i++) {
        answer=numValue[l-1];
        int c;
        if(numValue[l-1-i]<numValue[l-i-2]) {
            c=numValue[l-2-i];
            answer+=c;
            System.out.println("+"+c+" Now : "+answer);
        } else {
            c=numValue[l-2-i];
            answer-=c;
            System.out.println("-"+c+" Now : "+answer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is going wrong?
I do not see the correlation between your requirement and your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is that you are restarting your answer value each time in the for loop. this should fix your problem:

```
void calculate() {
    answer=numValue[l-1];
    for(int i=0;i<l-1;i++) {

        int c;
        if(numValue[l-1-i]<numValue[l-i-2]) {
            c=numValue[l-2-i];
            answer+=c;
            System.out.println("+"+c+" Now : "+answer);
        } else {
            c=numValue[l-2-i];
            answer-=c;
            System.out.println("-"+c+" Now : "+answer);
        }
    }
}
```

note that I moved the `answer=numValue[l-1];` out of your for loop to keep the answer previous value.

Answer (score 2):

The only issue is that you're overwriting the value of `answer` in every iteration of your `for` loop.
Following code will fix it:

```java
void calculate() {
  answer = numValue[l - 1];

  for (int i = 0; i < l - 1; i++) {
    int c;
    if (numValue[l - 1 - i] < numValue[l - i - 2]) {
      c = numValue[l - 2 - i];
      answer += c;
      System.out.println("+" + c + " Now : " + answer);
    } else {
      c = numValue[l - 2 - i];
      answer -= c;
      System.out.println("-" + c + " Now : " + answer);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you overwrite the answer on every loop using `answer=numValue[l-1];` you don't really perform the operation you printed above but rather only `10+500`. Move the initialization of `answer` out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would suggest looping backwards over the list

```
void calculate() {
    int i=numValue.length - 1
    sum = numValue[i];
    for(; i > 1; i--) {
        curr = numValue[i];
        System.out.print(curr);
        next = numValue[i-1];
        if (next < curr) {
            System.out.println("- " + next);
            sum -= next;
        } else {
            System.out.println("+ " + next);
            sum += next;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Result: " + sum);
}
```